# How to select dropdownlist value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, parsing, post

I have two pages "first.aspx" and "second.aspx".

In "first.aspx"

```
<form name="frm" method="post" action="second.aspx">
 <select name="ApiasDDL">
  <option value="36">Option 1</option>
  <option value="63">Option 2</option>
 </select>

 <input name="num" id="num_id" type="text" >
 <input name="ResultBtn" type="submit" class="button"">
</form>
```

I am making a `POST` request to "second.aspx". My code is..

```
//my postvars
byte[]  buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("num=123"); //here i want to select 
                                                     //dropdownlist value=36 also

HttpWebRequest WebReq = 
(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("second.aspx");

WebReq.Method = "POST";
....
....
```

How to select the dropdownlist `value=36` in `my postvars`?

Comment: What? This doesn't make sense, why would you do such a thing?

Comment: Use Hidden Field to Store dropdownlist selected value

Comment: @walther actually, in second.aspx page data is dynamic, it will change according to "num" and "value=36 or value=63". thats why i want to select the dropdownlist value.

Comment: @Viktor As walther is stated, the way you are doing is really strange especially posting between ASP.Net pages. What is the reason behind cross-site scripting?

Comment: I don't get it, the first form is already targeted at the second. I'm not sure where the code resides. Maybe it's for exercising the second page? I don't see any cross-site scripting.

Comment: I don't care if your data is dynamic or not, I haven't seen a completely static website for several years. Why don't you simply learn how to post data from one page to another using asp.net mechanisms instead of this crazy mess? Why do you create a web request manually, when you've already referenced the second page in html?

Comment: @walther Actually, I am developing a third party app, in which i want to parse second page directly. There is no need of first page. I write the code of first page because it is easy to understand for others that what I want.

Comment: It certainly isn't that obvious to us as you can see by the answers and the score of your question.... Since when do we parse a html page by posting some weird data to it from other page while selecting a dropdonwlist value? Does this really make sense to you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your POST data would need to look like this:

`"ApiasDDL=36&num=123&ResultBtn=Submit"`

If you want to see what POST data will be sent by your browser, the easiest way is:

1. Open Google Chrome
2. Hit F12 to bring up the developer tools
3. Click on the "Network" tab
4. Fill out the form on the page, and click "submit"
5. On the "Network" tab in the developer tools you can inspect the request details

(you can also use something like Fiddler, or a number of other tools)